# best practice to pass parameters between open pages

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm developing a Windows application (UWP) that has two pages, I want the best practice to pass parameters between pages.

it's my scenario:

We have two pages, **each open and remain at the middle of the screen** and a Button on each page, which send the message to the other page when we click on it.

I also want to pass information **continuously and repeatedly.**

**in Page1.cs:**

```
     Page2 page2;
         public Page1()
                {
                    this.InitializeComponent();         
                    CreatPage2();
                }

         // creat page 2
           private async void CreatPage2()
                {
                    var NewWindow = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
                    int NewWindowid = 0;

                    await NewWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
                    {
                        Frame newframe = new Frame();
                        newframe.Navigate(typeof(Page2), this);
                        Window.Current.Content = newframe;
                        Window.Current.Activate();
                        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "page2";
                        NewWindowid = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
                    });

                    await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(NewWindowid);
                }

                //Button


     private void ChangeP2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                  // send a message to the texblock in the page2
        page2.TexBlock2.Text=$"From page1 :{e.ToString()}";
// change  text color of the texblock in the page2
page2.Foreground= new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
                }
```

**in Page2.cs:**

```
  Page1 page1;
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        page1 = e.Parameter as Page1;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    public Page2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();         
    }



    //Button
     private void ChangeP1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
// send a message to the texblock in the page1
      page1.TexBlock1.Text=$"From page2 :{e.ToString()}";
// change  text color of the texblock in the page1
page1.Foreground= new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
    }
```

the above code just work for the page2 to the page1. (it can change the textblock of pagea).
Please help me, I can't find a solution that work on two pages

Comment: Have you tried simple events?

Comment: No, Please help me if you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naah… the best way is to use a standard pattern that consist of an app ViewModel class, which contains all the common app data that you want to use in the logic layer.

I always do it like this:

**1)** I use the MainPage automatically created as the "shell" of the app, with a property that is the `AppViewModel`.
The MainPage (and thus the `AppViewModel`) can be accessed from everywhere in the app, by setting itself as a static field in its own class.

This is the code, simpler than you think:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public AppViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new AppViewModel();
    public static MainPage Current { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Current = this;
    }
}
```

**2)** The `AppViewModel` itself is a class that must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, in order to enable bindable properties and functions.
It is common, among developers, to create a base class that implements it and then derive all the classes that needs bindable properties from it.

Here it is:

```
public class BaseBind : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you derive `AppViewModel` class (and all the other model and viewmodel classes) from it… populating it with all the common properties that you need to share across pages.
I have even added a derived property, in order to show how you can share even multiple data types at once, and a function:

```
public class AppViewModel : BaseBind
{
    public AppViewModel()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // All common app data
    private string sampleCommonString;
    public String SampleCommonString
    {
        get { return sampleCommonString; }
        set { SetProperty(ref sampleCommonString, value); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SampleDerivedProperty1)); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SampleDerivedProperty2)); }
    }

    public String SampleDerivedProperty1 =>  "return something based on SampleCommonString";

    public String SampleDerivedProperty2
    {
        get
        {
            <<evaluate SampleCommonString>>
            return "Same thing as SampleDerivedProperty1, but more explicit";
        }
    }

    // This is a property that you can use for functions and internal logic… but it CAN'T be binded
    public String SampleNOTBindableProperty { get; set; }

    public void SampleFunction()
    {
        // Insert code here.

        // The function has to be with NO parameters, in order to work with simple {x:Bind} markup.
        // If your function has to access some specific data, you can create a new bindable (or non) property, just as the ones above, and memorize the data there.
    }
}
```

3) Then, in order to access all this from another `Page`, just create an `AppViewModel` field in that page, as seen below:

```
public sealed partial class SecondPage : Page
{
    public AppViewModel ViewModel => MainPage.Current.ViewModel;

    public SecondPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

...and you can easily bind XAML controls properties to the `AppViewModel` itself:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleCommonString, Mode=OneWay}"/>
<Button Content="Sample content" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleFunction}"/>
```

(`Mode=OneWay` is for real-time binding, in order that the property is immediately updated even in the UI, while `Mode=TwoWay` is used for those properties that can be edited from the control itself, by the user, in order to interact with app logic).

Hope this helped.

Best regards and happy new year.

Comment: Does it for Xamarin platform ? My project is windows application.

Comment: Of course.    My answer fits perfectly to UWP apps in particular, but (with some minor changes) it works also on Xamarin projects; the general idea remains the same, thought.                Best regards

Comment: @Mayson   If my answer was helpful, you can accept it.

Comment: ,Thank you for your help, How can I use that in the windows application (UWP)? I can't use ViewModel API in UWP.

Comment: @Mayson    You don't need to use any additional API (apart the INotifyPropertyChenged interface)… just implement the code I wrote.