# How to structure my project to use x:Bind

Tags: c#, uwp, xbind, winui

After beeing used to structure my project in WPF on a light MVVM pattern, I'm looking into WINUI for a new project.
In the elapsed time, UWP and x:Bind did appear and it looks like the pattern can be much lighter. The whole concept of ViewModel has changed (maybe in a better way).

I'm looking for a "correct and maintainable" way to use x:Bind, to display Properties and call a function from a class.
In my App.xaml, I'm declaring a Configuration which contains all the sub-instances. Let's say a Camera. This Camera has an IP, and a method to call from the UI. What is the minimum code to be able to call and display those ?
For the moment, I have created a CameraView which is a UserControl. I have declared a public Camera object inside, which I can call and display but I don't see the way to affect this from my Configuration. This "link" between the view and the model.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a simpler way to implement MVVM: Microsoft itself shows how in its own samples, on GitHub.

However, to summarize it all, have a look at my answer in this question: [How to pass data between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063454/best-practice-to-pass-parameters-between-open-pages/54063936#54063936)

There I show, step after step, how to easily implement a working pattern to have a “shell” that holds all the app’s data.

Best regards